# Bound for Bottom-up Merge Sort

Tags: sorting

The below code from : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort/

```
/* Iterative mergesort function to sort arr[0...n-1] */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int n)
{
   int curr_size;  // For current size of subarrays to be merged
                   // curr_size varies from 1 to n/2
   int left_start; // For picking starting index of left subarray
                   // to be merged

   // Merge subarrays in bottom up manner.  First merge subarrays of
   // size 1 to create sorted subarrays of size 2, then merge subarrays
   // of size 2 to create sorted subarrays of size 4, and so on.
   for (curr_size=1; curr_size<=n-1; curr_size = 2*curr_size)
   {
       // Pick starting point of different subarrays of current size
       for (left_start=0; left_start<n-1; left_start += 2*curr_size)
       {
           // Find ending point of left subarray. mid+1 is starting 
           // point of right
           int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;

           int right_end = min(left_start + 2*curr_size - 1, n-1);

           // Merge Subarrays arr[left_start...mid] & arr[mid+1...right_end]
           merge(arr, left_start, mid, right_end);
       }
   }
}
```

I am not understand why the right_end should take the min of (left_start + 2*curr_size - 1) between (n-1).

I think the right_end should be left_start + 2*curr_size - 1 not n-1.

Comment: What if left_start + 2*curr_size - 1 is past the end of the array?

Comment: and what if mid is also past the end of array (in which case left_start to n-1 is just copied)? The line for mid should also include a min( ... , n-1). The code would be simpler if mid and right_end were ending indices (drop the -1), which is the more common way of implementing merge sort.